# Can I use hover for div?

Tags: html, css

Is css able to do something with my div while I'm hovering it by mouse? Or does it apply only to links?

I want to do something like this:

```
div:hover {
    background-color:black
}
```

Comment: You can experiment with HTML, CSS and JavaScript on sites like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I experimented in firefox but forgot to enable strict mode :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have said it certainly is possible. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/6K4bf/

Answer (score 10):

You can apply `:hover` styles to any renderable element on a page.

IE6 only supports that pseudo-class on links though.